# How to create a External Content Type equivalent to a Document Set?

Tags: bcs, external-content-type, document-set, custom-bcs

I'd like to create an External Content Type either inheriting from or equivalent to a Document Set. I'm not finding any good examples and Document Sets are derived from folders, so the API must be different for them. Any links to documentation or examples?

Answer (score 0):

Once a BDC field has been created in a list/library, you can add it to a Document Set Content Type in your list just as you would add it to any other Content Type.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Add the OTB Document Set Content Type to your list
2. Create a BDC field in the same list, selecting “Add to all Content Types”
3. The BDC field should now be “Used in” the Document Set Content Type (as shown below)